issue while sending data to controller with react/inertia on laravel
im having issues while sending the data of a form to the controller on laravel using react, this is my code:
editProduct component:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { MultiSelect } from 'react-multi-select-component';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

const EditProduct = ({ productId }) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [brands, setBrands] = useState([]);
    const [features, setFeatures] = useState([]);
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        description: '',
        quantity: '',
        price: '',
        visible: '1',
        brand_id: '',
        features: [],
        categories: [],
    });
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
    const [submitError, setSubmitError] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (productId) {
            fetchProduct();
            fetchOptions();
        }
    }, [productId]);

    const fetchProduct = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/products/${productId}`);
            const productData = await response.json();
            setProduct(productData);
            setFormData({
                name: productData.name,
                description: productData.description,
                quantity: productData.quantity,
                price: productData.price,
                visible: productData.visible ? '1' : '0',
                brand_id: productData.brand_id,
                features: productData.features.map(feature => feature.id.toString()),
                categories: productData.categories.map(category => category.id.toString()),
            });
            setImages(productData.images || []);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching product details:', error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const fetchOptions = async () => {
        try {
            const [brandsResponse, featuresResponse, categoriesResponse] = await Promise.all([
                fetch('/api/brands'),
                fetch('/api/features'),
                fetch('/api/categories'),
            ]);
            setBrands(await brandsResponse.json());
            setFeatures(await featuresResponse.json());
            setCategories(await categoriesResponse.json());
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching options:', error);
        }
    };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;
        setFormData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value
        }));
    };

    const handleFeatureChange = (selectedFeatures) => {
        setFormData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            features: selectedFeatures.map(feature => feature.value)
        }));
    };

    const handleCategoryChange = (selectedCategories) => {
        setFormData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            categories: selectedCategories.map(category => category.value)
        }));
    };

    const handleDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
        const maxFiles = 5;
        if (images.length + acceptedFiles.length > maxFiles) {
            setErrors(['You can only upload up to 5 images.']);
            return;
        }
        setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, ...acceptedFiles]);
        setErrors([]);
    }, [images]);

    const handleDropRejected = useCallback((rejectedFiles) => {
        const sizeLimit = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2MB size limit
        const errors = rejectedFiles.map(file => {
            if (file.size > sizeLimit) {
                return `${file.file.name} is too large. Maximum size is 2MB.`;
            }
            return `${file.file.name} was rejected. Only JPEG and PNG formats are allowed.`;
        });
        setErrors(errors);
    }, []);

    const handleImageRemove = (index) => {
        const newImages = [...images];
        newImages.splice(index, 1);
        setImages(newImages);
    };

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
        onDrop: handleDrop,
        onDropRejected: handleDropRejected,
        accept: 'image/jpeg, image/png', // Only allow JPEG and PNG images
        maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, // 2MB size limit
    });

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const data = new FormData();
        // Append form data
        Object.keys(formData).forEach(key => {
            if (Array.isArray(formData[key])) {
                formData[key].forEach(item => {
                    data.append(`${key}[]`, item);
                });
            } else {
                data.append(key, formData[key]);
            }
        });
    
        // Append images
        images.forEach(image => {
            if (image instanceof File || image instanceof Blob) {
                data.append('images[]', image);
            }
        });
    
        fetch(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: data,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json', // Optional, to specify the expected response format
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Product updated successfully:', data);
            // Handle success
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was an error updating the product!', error);
            // Handle error
        });
    };

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div className="py-12">
            <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div className="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div className="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                        <h2 className="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight mb-6">Edit Product</h2>
                        {submitError && (
                            <div className="mb-4 text-red-600">{submitError}</div>
                        )}
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="name" className="block text-gray-700">Name</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="name"
                                    name="name"
                                    value={formData.name}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    className="form-input mt-1 block w-full"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="description" className="block text-gray-700">Description</label>
                                <textarea
                                    id="description"
                                    name="description"
                                    value={formData.description}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    className="form-textarea mt-1 block w-full"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="quantity" className="block text-gray-700">Quantity</label>
                                <input
                                    type="number"
                                    id="quantity"
                                    name="quantity"
                                    value={formData.quantity}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    className="form-input mt-1 block w-full"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="price" className="block text-gray-700">Price</label>
                                <input
                                    type="number"
                                    id="price"
                                    name="price"
                                    value={formData.price}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    className="form-input mt-1 block w-full"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="visible" className="block text-gray-700">Visible</label>
                                <select
                                    id="visible"
                                    name="visible"
                                    value={formData.visible}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    className="form-select mt-1 block w-full"
                                >
                                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                    <option value="0">No</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="brand_id" className="block text-gray-700">Brand</label>
                                <select
                                    id="brand_id"
                                    name="brand_id"
                                    value={formData.brand_id}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    className="form-select mt-1 block w-full"
                                >
                                    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                                    {brands.map(brand => (
                                        <option key={brand.id} value={brand.id}>
                                            {brand.name}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="features" className="block text-gray-700">Features</label>
                                <MultiSelect
                                    options={features.map(feature => ({ label: feature.name, value: feature.id }))}
                                    value={formData.features.map(featureId => ({
                                        label: features.find(feature => feature.id === parseInt(featureId))?.name,
                                        value: featureId
                                    }))}
                                    onChange={handleFeatureChange}
                                    labelledBy="Select features"
                                    className="mt-1 block w-full"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label htmlFor="categories" className="block text-gray-700">Categories</label>
                                <MultiSelect
                                    options={categories.map(category => ({ label: category.name, value: category.id }))}
                                    value={formData.categories.map(categoryId => ({
                                        label: categories.find(category => category.id === parseInt(categoryId))?.name,
                                        value: categoryId
                                    }))}
                                    onChange={handleCategoryChange}
                                    labelledBy="Select categories"
                                    className="mt-1 block w-full"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-4">
                                <label className="block text-gray-700">Product Images</label>
                                <div {...getRootProps()} className="mt-1 block w-full p-6 border-2 border-dashed border-gray-300 rounded-md text-center cursor-pointer">
                                    <input {...getInputProps()} />
                                    <p>Drag & drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
                                </div>
                                {errors.length > 0 && (
                                    <div className="mt-2 text-red-600">
                                        {errors.map((error, index) => (
                                            <p key={index}>{error}</p>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                )}
                                <div className="mt-4">
                                    {images.map((image, index) => (
                                        <div key={index} className="flex items-center justify-between mb-2">
                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                <img
                                                    src={image instanceof File || image instanceof Blob ? URL.createObjectURL(image) : `/storage/${image.image}`}
                                                    alt={image.name || 'Image'}
                                                    className="w-16 h-16 object-cover mr-4"
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <button
                                                type="button"
                                                className="text-red-500 hover:text-red-700 focus:outline-none"
                                                onClick={() => handleImageRemove(index)}
                                            >
                                                Remove
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex items-center justify-end">
                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    className="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
                                >
                                    Update Product
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EditProduct;

The problem is that the info of the form is not reaching the method of the controller:
on the api file:
Route::put('/products/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'update']); 

the data is being sent:

BUT, if i put on the controller
dd($request->all());

it just doesnt arrive:

This is the controller code:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\ProductImage;
use App\Models\ProductFeature;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->input('query');

        // Query products with eager loading
        $products = Product::with(['brand', 'features', 'images'])
            ->when($query, function ($queryBuilder) use ($query) {
                // Filter by name, description, price, quantity, brand name, etc.
                $queryBuilder->where('name', 'like', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhere('price', 'like', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhere('quantity', 'like', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhereHas('brand', function ($brandQuery) use ($query) {
                        $brandQuery->where('name', 'like', "%$query%");
                    });
            })
            ->paginate(10); 

        return response()->json($products);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'description' => 'required|string',
        'quantity' => 'required|integer',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'visible' => 'required|boolean',
        'brand_id' => 'required|exists:brands,id',
        'selectedFeatures' => 'array',
        'selectedCategories' => 'array',
        'selectedFeatures.*' => 'exists:features,id',
        'selectedCategories.*' => 'exists:categories,id',
        'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png|max:2048', // Ensure validation for images
    ]);

    $product = Product::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'quantity' => $request->quantity,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'visible' => $request->visible,
        'brand_id' => $request->brand_id,
    ]);

    // Handle the images
        if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
            // Get original image name
            $originalName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            
            // Remove spaces and replace with underscores
            $nameWithoutSpaces = str_replace(' ', '_', pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
            
            // Append current date and time
            $timestamp = now()->format('Ymd_His');
            $newName = $nameWithoutSpaces . '_' . $timestamp . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            
            // Store the image in the public storage
            $path = $image->storeAs('public/product_images', $newName);

            // Save image path and name in the database
            $product->images()->create([
                'image' => str_replace('public/', '', $path), // Store relative path for public storage
                'principal' => false, // Or set according to your logic
                'visible' => true, // Or set according to your logic
            ]);
        }
    }

    // Attach categories
    if ($request->has('selectedCategories')) {
        $product->categories()->attach($request->selectedCategories);
    }

    // Attach features with additional attributes
    if ($request->has('selectedFeatures')) {
        foreach ($request->selectedFeatures as $featureId) {
            $product->features()->attach($featureId, [
                'principal' => false,
                'order' => 0, // Set default values or handle accordingly
                'visible' => true, // Set default values or handle accordingly
            ]);
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Product created successfully.']);
}


    

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    Log::info('Update method called');
    Log::info('Request data: ', $request->all());
    
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    // Validate the request data
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'description' => 'required|string',
        'quantity' => 'required|integer',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'visible' => 'required|boolean',
        'brand_id' => 'required|exists:brands,id',
        'selectedFeatures' => 'array',
        'selectedCategories' => 'array',
        'selectedFeatures.*' => 'exists:features,id',
        'selectedCategories.*' => 'exists:categories,id',
        'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png|max:2048',
    ]);

    

    // Update the product's basic information
    $product->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'quantity' => $request->quantity,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'visible' => $request->visible,
        'brand_id' => $request->brand_id,
    ]);

    // Handle images
    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
        // Delete old images if necessary
        foreach ($product->images as $existingImage) {
            Storage::delete('public/' . $existingImage->image);
            $existingImage->delete();
        }

        // Store new images
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
            $originalName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $nameWithoutSpaces = str_replace(' ', '_', pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
            $timestamp = now()->format('Ymd_His');
            $newName = $nameWithoutSpaces . '_' . $timestamp . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            
            // Store the image and save the path
            $path = $image->storeAs('public/product_images', $newName);

            $product->images()->create([
                'image' => 'product_images/' . $newName,
                'principal' => false,
                'visible' => true,
            ]);
        }
    }

    // Sync categories
    $product->categories()->sync($request->selectedCategories);

    // Sync features with additional attributes
    $product->features()->sync([]);
    if ($request->has('selectedFeatures')) {
        foreach ($request->selectedFeatures as $featureId) {
            $product->features()->attach($featureId, [
                'principal' => false,
                'order' => 0,
                'visible' => true,
            ]);
        }
    }

    // Return a success response
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Product updated successfully.']);
}

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = Product::with(['features', 'categories', 'brand'])->findOrFail($id);
        return Inertia::render('EditProductPage', [
            'productId' => $id,
            'product' => $product
        ]);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::with(['brand', 'features', 'categories', 'images'])->findOrFail($id);
        return response()->json($product);
    }

}

i have tried changing axios to fetch but im afraid the problem is more on the backend side, however im not sure, can someone please give me a hand on here? im a newbie on both laravel and react thanks!

First of all you should sent a put request with fetch, and second, please show us your controller method update

just added the controller code @henrikhannewijk

Okay thanks, but may i ask how u expect data to be available in your controller when u do not send data to your controller? use a put request instead of a get request and also send the form as body, the code u provided does not do that.

Well, the data is being sent on:
body: data, as a matter of fact i can see it on the payload of the dev tools,
i get this error:
422 Unprocessable Content

just found out what the problem was, on the handleSubmit function
 fetch(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json', // Optional, to specify the expected response format
            'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PUT' // Method spoofing using headers
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Product updated successfully:', data);
        // Handle success
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error updating the product!', error);
        // Handle error
    });
};

it was necesary to "spoof" the method with the headers:
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PUT' // Method spoofing using headers

Thanks to everyone to took the time to check and read my question!
